# Are there any name combinations that may not be used?

Tags: minhag, names

Are there any combinations of names that may not be given? There are many names which aren't commonly paired together but is there any reason not to or just common practice and preference?

Comment: It is assur to give a rashas name

Comment: My question is about combination of names rather than individual names themselves

Comment: I have seen a discussion (I think Ksav Sofer but I am not sure) which mentions that names of differing or conflicting characters or personalities should not be given.  For example, if one grandparent is known for a particular personality trait and the other grandparent for a trait that (while good in itself) would cause a conflict if both are in the same person, the child should not be named after the two of them. This is from memory only and I do not have a copy of the Chasam Sofer or Ksav Sofer available in which one of them talks about naming babies.